# Don't allow JavaScript in the content area

Tags: javascript, the-content

Is there any way to disable or remove JavaScript in the page/post content area?

So if there was any `<script>` tags it would remove them or ignore them when outputting `the_content();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_script_tag' );

function remove_script_tag( $content )
{
    return strip_tags( $content, '<script>' );
}
```

When you also want the content of the tag to be removed you could use this one:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_script_tag_and_content' );

function remove_script_tag_and_content( $content )
{
    $striped_text =  preg_replace('@<script>.*?<\/script>@si', '', $content);
    return $striped_text;
}
```

Comment: that works, but does still output the JavaScript as plain text, is there anyway to completely remove it?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Perfect! just what i was looking for, thank you :)